# Null pointer exception while creating entity object

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have an entity and i am creating object for it. object is created and i can set the values. But reference shows null. I am not getting why. Please check my code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "a_table")
public class A {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -8674959693713707364L;

/** The id. */
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY, generator = "IdOrGenerated")
@GenericGenerator(name = "IdOrGenerated", strategy = "foo.IdOrGenerated")
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;

private Creator creator;

public A() {
}

public A(Creator pCreator) {
    this.creator = pCreator;
}

//setters and getters for id and creator

}
```

In class B i am creating object `A a = new A();`
when i debug and see 'a' value is null.

Comment: What is null exactly ?

Comment: @Berger reference 'a' is null

Comment: could you show us part of B class where you are getting null..

Comment: Mixing local variable with class members? Member stays null because you accidentally assigned to local var?

Comment: In class B i tried to create object of A and i am setting value for creator. I kept debugger at a.setCreator(); when i see 'a' in variables while debugging, its null and i can set the values!!

Comment: @chrylis its not a duplicate man.

Comment: @user1770589 try updating the question with more relevent code so that you can convince its not a duplicate..